# dd write vs read performance

Tags: hard-disk, performance, dd

I have recently done some performance tests on a new server (using dd) and wonder why read performance is so much worse than write performance?  Shouldn't it be another way around?

file size was in both tests 550GB,
read: 
in seconds: 3704
in MB/s: 148

and write:
in seconds: 1539
in MB/s: 357

write command:

```
time sh -c "dd if=/dev/zero of=/local/postgresql/bigfile 
bs=8k count=67108864 && sync"
```

read command:

```
time dd if=/local/postgresql/bigfile of=/dev/null bs=8k
```

bash time command output:

```
real: 61m44.335s
user: 0m12.721s
sys: 10m35.884s
```

Bonnie++ results
command:

```
bonnie++ -f -D -n 0 -u root -d /local/postgresql/
```

results are for file that was twice as big as RAM size.

write:

419 918 K/sec

read:

~ 187 000 K/sec

Comment: which kind of test did you run? can you post the whole command line you used? How much ram do you have in your environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the write sync flags to test performance, to ensure you are actually writing on disk and not on cache. Use `conv=fdatasync` to force a sync of buffers after writing has ended. See [here](https://romanrm.net/dd-benchmark) for details.

```
time dd .... conv=fdatasync
```

for read test, discard caches before testing:

```
flush
echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
time dd ....
```

Comment: Also, note that it may be very possible for the write speed to be faster than read speed: for example, if your write are sequential and read are not (and you have a spinning disk). This is particularly true in RAID systems

Comment: I did something similar: "dd if=/dev/zero of=/local/postgresql/bigfile bs=8k count=67108864 && sync" so sync was performed at the end of operation. drop_caches was used between all tests. Is it pretty the same or not?

Comment: @MarcinBykowski using sync at the end does not affect the time reported by `dd`, which has already written your results before even evaluating `sync` command...

Comment: ok, but it should affect bash time command? post edited with bash output.

Comment: @MarcinBykowski I guess so. Probably your system is really faster at writing than reading. Are you sure the reading is sequential?

Comment: hmm maybe that's the question? I'm not sure about that it was done on matrix with dedicated software with own algorith to create luns, could it be the reason?

Comment: @MarcinBykowski if you have a striped RAID with many disks your sequential throughput will be high, but seek time would be the worst of all disks. For writing this may be mitigated by controller/disk level caches, but for reading you have to pay for it. That's the reason I'm asking whether he's sure about doing a sequential reading (for example it can be done by reading the block device directly)

Comment: so striped disks could be the reason? thank you for this idea, I'll try to test it.

Answer (score 1):

What was the command you used? `dd` does **very** different things related to percormance depending on the options.

But from what you write,

I think you were reading small blocks, which will get read from the disk as you ask for them, roughly.

And you where writing small blocks, which will be written to the disk when the kernel feels it has time to do it - not when `dd` writes them out.

That would already explain the difference, right?

Comment: I have just edited my post with the exact command I have used. Yes, blocks were 8k.

Answer (score 1):

I'm very doubtful that you can get meaningful benchmarks from `dd`. `dd` just shows you how large sequential reads or large sequential asynchronous writes perform between various devices. As long as your workload consists mainly of copying large files between these filesystems you're alright. I doubt that's your workload, though.

Your best bet is to profile disk usage and use a real I/O benchmarking suite (link `bonnie++` or something) to test how much effect changing various tunables has. For a database, I would expect a lot of random reads. Setting `noatime` and doing `data=writeback` on your main data files (with regular backups being made) is probably the best you can do with what information we have so far.

To answer what seems to be your bigger question, it's because asynchronous writes (like those made by `dd`) can get buffered in memory and committed to disk. They're *kind* of I/O bound insofar as queues and buffers can fill and you would have to wait for them to become available again (by committing to disk) before you can stack more on.

Reads, on the other hand, are definitionally I/O bound so you don't usually get the same asynchronous action going on. You can play around with `read_ahead_kb` and the like so that more sequential data is read into memory in anticipation of being asked for by the workload in the near future.

That's about all I can think to answer with what we know so far. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: after dd test I did test with bonnie++, I have edited my post with results.

Comment: using `conv=fdatasync` option or using `sync` command afterwards should solve the cache issue.

Comment: @Joel Davis as I have red in newer kernels default option is relatime (aliases with atime), so setting the parameter to noatime will reduce write operations not that much as before. in my tests haven't seen any differences as well.

Comment: @pqnet - yes thank you I'll for sure use this option with next test.

Comment: @pqnet that's still not a good test as that just does asynchronous writes followed by an `fsync`. It gets things closer to the mark but I'd wager the vast majority of writes to database files are synchronous. The cache thing isn't that much of an issue. The real issue is that `dd` isn't good at benchmarking, it's basically just a really beefed up `cp` command.

Comment: @JoelDavis for rough estimate even `dd` can give you an idea of what the device speed is, and as you can see the final result are pretty similar. The question is more about *why I am observing these numbers* than *what is the proper way to benchmark a machine for database use*. Don't jump ahead just because you read `/local/postgresql/`.

Comment: @pqnet -agreed- why still, using 2 different programs writes are faster than reads?

Comment: @pgnet hardware specs can tell you how fast a device is without testing. The purpose of software testing is to determine fitness for purpose. I'll concede that you got the numbers closer but my point is that `async+fsync` != `O_SYNC` and that `dd` isn't a benchmarking tool. I realize that's not the question but you can't expect someone to ask about something they don't know about. The OP could just be unaware that `dd` isn't a good tool for benchmarking. `bonnie++` isn't significantly harder to learn and it's more to the point.

Comment: @MarcinBykowski I ran that command on my system and actually ended up with faster reads than writes (probably due to the filesystem cache). Can you post the full command output? I want to see where the numbers are coming from. `-D` should have enabled direct I/O (forcing synchronous reads/writes).